# How to run bash script as background process on system forever?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, init

I have a script(sync.sh) which runs a while loop inside for syncing.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
     #my PHP scripts runs parallel 

     wait
     sleep 60
done
```

I want to run this script independently forever in my vm.

I know I can run this sh file as a **background process by using nohup, disown command**.

***But what I want to know is? How can I run this .sh file on system restart or it process is killed. How to start .sh file automatically without terminal command in Ubuntu VM.(Like we have starting Apache, MySQL services on system start)***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for me ... *"run this script independently forever"* ... requires a means of periodically verifying the script is running (eg, did the script die? did someone/something kill the script?); what I typically do is add logic to the script that allows it to check if a copy (of itself) is already running and then react accordingly, and then I schedule (in cron) the script to run on a regular basis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using systemD, you should create a service for your script sync.sh, this file will be:

```
/lib/systemd/system/sync.service
```

You can edit this file (with 'root' or 'sudo' privileges) so it contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script for Sync

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sync.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, you re-load your systemD daemon (so it knows that a service has been added) :

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then you can enable your service (so it will be launched at every system start:

```
sudo systemctl enable sync.service
```

Then you can start it manually so it will be started right away, not waiting for the next system restart :

```
sudo systemctl start sync.service
```

(of course, you can change the name of your service and it's not necessarily called "sync.service"

Comment: Thanks. This is what I actually needed.